# Is this a loose part of MacBook Pro 2010 (15" version)?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, repair, macos

Upon opening a MacBook Pro (15" Mid-2010, 2.67 GHz i7, 8GB, GT330, Hi-Res anti-glare display), I noticed a small loose plastic part. Its diameter is ~5mm.

Does this plastic part belong to the MacBook Pro?

Should this plastic part be attached to something?

Below are pictures taken from two opposing sides, and from the lateral side (object leaned to watchmaker's screwdriver)

[image]

[image]

[image: lateral view, object leaning on watchmaker's screwdriver]

Comment: Ummm... you sure that's not a button, like from a coat?

Comment: While it bears some resemblance with a button, it is too small for any non-decorative button, and doesn't look like a button from the lateral view. Also it is very thin, and can be bent easily (unlike any button).

Comment: Can you add an approximate diameter in the question?

Comment: The diameter of 5 mm is listed in original post

Comment: I'm thinking it might be a membrane that goes over a speaker or microphone. I have seen similar things in radios and other electronic equipment but not specifically in a MacBook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I found out that this part forms the inner part of the rubber stands at the bottom of the laptop.